# Extract single element from list in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming, sequence

I want to extract a single item from a sequence in F#, or give an error if there is none or more than one. What is the best way to do this?

I currently have

```
let element = data |> (Seq.filter (function | RawXml.Property (x) -> false | _ -> true))
                   |> List.of_seq
                   |> (function head :: [] -> head | head :: tail -> failwith("Too many elements.") | [] -> failwith("Empty sequence"))
                   |> (fun x -> match x with MyElement (data) -> x | _ -> failwith("Bad element."))
```

It seems to work, but is it really the best way?

Edit: As I was pointed in the right direction, I came up with the following:

```
let element = data |> (Seq.filter (function | RawXml.Property (x) -> false | _ -> true))
                   |> (fun s -> if Seq.length s <> 1 then failwith("The sequence must have exactly one item") else s)
                   |> Seq.hd
                   |> (fun x -> match x with MyElement (_) -> x | _ -> failwith("Bad element."))
```

I guess it's a little nicer.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sequence and what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't find that necessary. I want to find the first value and give an error if there is more than one. That's it

Comment: +1 - you want an F# equivalent to a useful LINQ operator (System.Linq.Enumerable.Single) - normally it's the other way round!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequence has a find function.

```
val find : ('a -> bool) -> seq<'a> -> 'a
```

but if you want to ensure that the seq has only one element, then doing a Seq.filter, then  take the length after filter and ensure it equals one, and then take the head. All in Seq, no need to convert to a list.

Edit:
On a side note, I *was* going to suggest checking that the *tail* of a result is empty (O(1), instead of using the function `length` (O(n)). Tail isn't a part of seq, but I think you can work out a good way to emulate that functionality.

Comment: On long sequences with many matches this will fail very slowly, on infinite sequences then the correct result is to keep calculating to infinity or terminate early but it won't either (this difference is pretty marginal in utility though)

Comment: Yeah, I think infinite seq are going to get you either way, try to find something that isn't in an infinite list...

But, the point of taking the length instead of just checking that the tail is empty is a good one, and what I originally wanted to mention, but seq doesn't have a tail function. I modified my post to reflect that limitation and use a function that's O(1).

Thanks

Comment: Seq's skip function will function as an alternate to tail, Seq.skip 1 filter should be empty and seq.hd after that will check it has at least one (hd will throw it's own exception if it's empty which is useful)

Answer (score 4):

done in the style of the existing sequence standard functions

```
#light

let findOneAndOnlyOne f (ie : seq<'a>)  = 
    use e = ie.GetEnumerator()
    let mutable res = None 
    while (e.MoveNext()) do
        if f e.Current then
            match res with
            | None -> res <- Some e.Current
            | _ -> invalid_arg "there is more than one match"          
    done;
    match res with
        | None -> invalid_arg "no match"          
        | _ -> res.Value
```

You could do a pure implementation but it will end up jumping through hoops to be correct and efficient (terminating quickly on the second match really calls for a flag saying 'I found it already')

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer would be to use Seq.exactlyOne which raises an ArgumentException

Comment: This is the right answer! It will raise a System.ArgumentNullException in the case of zero elements, and System.ArgumentException in the case of more than one.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with using the existing library function?

```
let single f xs = System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(xs, System.Func<_,_>(f))

[1;2;3] |> single ((=) 4)
```

Comment: This is one of the only extension methods in System.Linq that doesn't have an equivalent in the F# modules. Not sure whether there's a reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
> let only s =
    if not(Seq.isEmpty s) && Seq.isEmpty(Seq.skip 1 s) then
      Seq.hd s
    else
      raise(System.ArgumentException "only");;
val only : seq<'a> -> 'a
```

Comment: Don't both skip and hd both compute the head (so if there are side effects, you see them twice)?

Comment: Yes. If they are slow or have undesirable side effects then you'll want to optimise this.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents... this works with the option type so I can use it in my custom maybe monad. could be modified very easy though to work with exceptions instead

```
let Single (items : seq<'a>) =
    let single (e : IEnumerator<'a>) =
        if e.MoveNext () then
            if e.MoveNext () then
                raise(InvalidOperationException "more than one, expecting one")
            else
                Some e.Current
        else
            None
    use e = items.GetEnumerator ()
    e |> single
```

Comment: You should probably cache `e.Current` before calling `MoveNext` a second time, since some enumerators might throw an exception if `e.Current` is accessed after reaching the end of the enumeration.  Also, I don't see any benefit to creating the nested `single` function, since it's always called exactly once.  It also seems strange to return `None` if there are 0 elements, but throw an exception if there are more than 1 - in that case I'd call the method `AtMostOne` rather than `Single`.

Comment: the nested function is there just to be clear it's actually working on IEnumerator and not IEnumerable. the none and some are there so this plugs into my maybe monad, in that context it reads very naturally. I use this in data access a lot for chaining dependent calls. when none short circuit when some continue kinda thing

Comment: The use of an option type is fine, but then why not return `None` if there's more than one element too?  To me, if you're expecting to have a single element, then the 0-element and 2-or-more-element cases are probably equally exceptional and should be treated in the same fashion unless there's a compelling rationale for distinguishing them (in which case the method should probably be called something more specific for clarity, like `AtMostOne`).